# KMS Activation count w7 ent

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, licensing, kms

On my KMS host (Windows Server 2008 R2), when i do a `slmgr.vbs /dli`, I dont see any Current Count fied, i only see this:

> Name: Windows Server(R), Server Standard edition
>   Description: Windows Operating System - Windows Server(R), VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
>   This license is not in use.
>   License Status: Unlicensed
>   Please use `slmgr.vbs /ato` 
>   to activate and update KMS client information in order to update
>   values.

I have at leat 8 machines so far that have tried to activate (/ato command run on the machines but got an error).

So i did the `/ato` on the server also but nothing has changed since.

Plus i see a whole bunch of other winddows server with different keys (OEM ...) and i dont know why.

Any idea where i can see the number of activation count or what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: 
1-I have the _vlmcs dns record and i know it's working because this server also activates office 2010.
2- I cant remember the way i did it, but i did it only for office 2010 pro. So now i'm trying to add windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run through the steps that you followed to install and activate your KMS key? Do you show that key as activated on Microsoft's website? Do you see a `_VLMCS` srv record in the `_tcp` zone of your main AD zone?

Comment: How many Windows 7 clients are on the network?

Comment: in fact i have office 2010 pro on that KMS server so i knwo the KMS server is working.
I just dont know how to deal with the windows 7 machines. So far i have in VAMT 2.0 7 win7 enterprise.

Comment: i see stuff for office 2010 :

Name: Microsoft Office 2010, KMSHost edition
Description: Microsoft Office 2010 KMS, VOLUME_KMS channel
Partial Product Key: XXXX
License Status: Licensed

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 10
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 5374
    Failed requests received: 10
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 5009
   and so on

Comment: Office KMS components are separate from Windows KMS components. Can you please answer the questions that I asked by editing the details into your question?

Comment: Just want to verify that you used a Windows 2008 R2 KMS Host key to activate the actual server and not a MAK or generic KMS client key to register/activate the server.

Comment: how could i see that?

Comment: MDMarra, i've edited my post :)

Comment: if you are not sure, I would go back and remove the current key and activate the host with a KMS host key (first make sure you have a KMS host key)

Comment: In VLSC i only see Win7 and Win8 KMS, should i use this?

Comment: no. you will need a windows 2008 R2 KMS host key. Go jump on your MS licensing site and pull up your keys for 2008 R2 and find the KMS key as opposed to the MAK key. Use slmgr to remove the current key, add the 2008 R2 KMS key, and activate the new key. The 2008 R2 KMS key will activate win7 KMS clients once it reaches the 25 device threshold.

Comment: that solved my issue i guess, now i have the error message sayign there's not enough KMS client to activate!!!
Merci!!! (How do i mark you answer as the good one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your screen shot shows the line "Windows Server(R), VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel" which seems to indicate your 2008 R2 KMS host was activated using a KMS client or MAK key. This means you cannot use this host to activate windows 7 clients.

Find your 2008 R2 KMS key from the microsoft licensing site and remove the current key and use the 2008 R2 KMS key to activate the KMS host.

to remove the current key:

> slmgr.vbs /upk

Install new KMS key:

> slmgr.vbs /ipk <2008 R2 KMS key>

Activate server with KMS key:

> slmgr.vbs /ato

The same minimum thresholds mentioned by Brian must still be met. Running "slmgr.vbs /dli" should display the line "VOLUME_KMS_R2_A Channel" or something similar. It should also show the number activation attempts even if you are under the threshold. The 2008 R2 KMS host key will activate windows 7 OS clients. You will not need to install a windows 7 KMS key on your server.

Comment: i see now the Current Count field, and i am at 24/25!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to hit the minimum required KMS requests (based on client type) before they show up in the output of `slmgr.vbs /dli`.

- For Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2 — at least 5
  computers
- For Windows Vista or Windows 7 — at least 25 computers
- For Office 2010, Visio 2010, Project 2010, or a combination of the three — at least 5 computers (however, for Office 2010 suites and    applications, Microsoft recommends MAK activation if organizations have fewer than 50 computers)

Comment: ho ok i see, i was going to wait and  see but wanted to make sure i dont have something weird before :)
I'll post when i have 25 computer which shouldn't be too long to get.

Comment: Computers will show up in `slmgr /dli` before you hit the threshold under `OOBE Grace`.